# Converting nested lists to parent lists

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, int

So, I am just trying to solve a problem on [hackerrank.com](https://www.hackerrank.com/)

Here is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    num_list = []
    for numberOfCommands in range(N):
        command , * numbers = input().split(" ")
        numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers]
        print(numbers)
        if command == 'insert':
            num_list.insert(numbers[0],numbers[1:])
        elif command == 'print':
            print(num_list)
        else:
            num_list.command(numbers[0])
```

The problem is when I print `list` it prints nested lists. What I want is to creating a single list of `int`s.

Comment: Don't use the name `list`, it already refers to the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) type.  `list.insert(numbers[0],numbers[1:])` inserts the list slice `numbers[1:]` at index `numbers[0]`.  Is that really what you intend?

Comment: changed name list to num_list but the output is same

Comment: Could you add (as text in your question) what the problem you're trying to solve is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

You can [flatten a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/9067615) like so:

```
flat_list = [element for sublist in num_list for element in sublist]
print(flat_list)
```

Or using the inbuilt `itertools.chain`:

```
import itertools

list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(num_list))
```